# How can I extract meta data from various video file formats?

Tags: java, video

How can I extract meta data from various video file formats, especially the Resolution and the type of codec used. (But also all other stuff like author). I was not able to find a library for that.

Answer (score 7):

I have found [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/), which supplies dozens of technical and tag information about a video or audio file.

There is a JNI wrapper for MediaInfo in [subs4me's source tree](https://github.com/dudhead/subs4me) that I find very useful.

Here are some code snippets that show how to extract some information from a media file:

```
File file         = new File("path/to/my/file");
MediaInfo info    = new MediaInfo();

info.open(file);

String format     = info.get(MediaInfo.StreamKind.Video, i, "Format", 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Text,
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Name);

int bitRate       = info.get(MediaInfo.StreamKind.Video, i, "BitRate", 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Text,
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Name);

float frameRate   = info.get(MediaInfo.StreamKind.Video, i, "FrameRate", 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Text, 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Name);

short width       = info.get(MediaInfo.StreamKind.Video, i, "Width", 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Text, 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Name);

int audioBitrate  = info.get(MediaInfo.StreamKind.Audio, i, "BitRate", 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Text, 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Name);

int audioChannels = info.get(MediaInfo.StreamKind.Audio, i, "Channels", 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Text, 
                             MediaInfo.InfoKind.Name);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [vikiiii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907687/vikiiii) solutions works, but I found :

- It still required a bit of work to get everything running on my desktop. (download the dll, extract the code, browse files...)
- We have no clue of the constants (like "BitRate") available

As a consequence I installed the Windows MediaInfo application and search which are the Keys available to create some java Enum and ease usage.

I created a repository  on github https://github.com/clun/movies-metadata to have everything in the same place. Just run `mvn:test` on the sample project to get informations on samples MP4, OGG, AVI, FLV, WEBM and MKV.

Here the sample code of the test :

```
  MovieMetadata movieMedataData = new MovieMetadata("./src/test/resources/small.mkv");
    movieMedataData.get(General.FORMAT);
    movieMedataData.get(Video.DURATION_STRING);
    movieMedataData.get(Video.WIDTH_STRING);
    movieMedataData.get(Video.HEIGHT_STRING);
    movieMedataData.get(Video.BITRATE_STRING);
    movieMedataData.get(Audio.COMPRESSION_RATIO);
    //...
```