# how can i get the resolution of a video uploaded with file upload in primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, primefaces-fileupload

I've seen examples to do this with images something like that:

```
public void getFile(FileUploadEvent archivo) {
  UploadedFile uploadedFile = archivo.getFile();
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedFile.getInputstream());
  BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));  
  int width = bufferedImage.getWidth();
  int height = bufferedImage.getHeight();
}
```

But, this should work for mp3,mp4 or mov? Or there is another way to get this information?
I've been looking for an example but haven't found anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract meta data from various video file formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941961/how-can-i-extract-meta-data-from-various-video-file-formats)

Comment: No, according to its documentation, it doesn't work for mp4 and mov files and I need to get the information from those files as well. Thanks!